# Chrome crashes while performing regex matching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, google-chrome

I'm trying to match 50 email ids seperated by comma (,) with a regex and every time i try to perform this operation chrome crashes. But, Safari seems to handle it. I'm using the below code

```
var emailValidator = /^([\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4},*[\W]*)+$/;
if(!formData.emailList.match(emailValidator))
    showWarning("Invalid email ids");
```

Can someone tell me why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: p/s: RegEx-based email validation is next to impossible. you risk excluding a lot of perfectly valid email addresses. http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Comment: Do you know that TLDs is much more than 2 to 4 letters? Have a look at https://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
*[\W]*)+
```

This is because of catastrophic backtrackng because of this component of yours.Remove this and it will work fine.

See here failing because of backtracking

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/73

Improved

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/74

Or draft your regex in this way

```
^[\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}(?:,[\w+-.%]+@[\w-.]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4})*$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vN3sH3/75